# SFDX 2GP instructions?

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx

Looking for more (and up-to-date) documentation on SFDX Package2. Ideally, a tutorial on setting up package2-descriptor.json and package2-manifest.json files. I know it's still Beta, so docs are sparse.

I've watched all the youtube vids from TrailheaDX and Dreamforce. Any leads?

Comment: Check the relevant success community for the pilot. They'll have the most recent documentation listed in the sidebar. I dont have a link offhand, but if you're in the pilot, you should have access to the success org.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @battery.cord. That's where I went just now. Looks like this is the most recent FAQ: https://sfdc-db-gmail.github.io/#h.bstbewcztt9f

I'm about to submit an app for AppExchange and wanted to use 2GP, but it appears that's not available yet. Bummer.